# Python: Counting CPU-cycles between 2 happenings on data-link-layer

Tags: linux, python-2.7, scapy, data-link-layer, cpu-cycles

There are 2 hosts: local & remote.
I want to do follows:

Send from local machine on L2 (data-link-layer) RTS-frame, and check CPU-cycles at that moment (**moment A**). Frame is receiving on remote machine. Remote sends answer. 
On local i'm catching this answer (CTS-frame). And again check CPU-cycles (**moment B**).

I need to count CPU-cycles between A and B: **Ncycles = B-A** (think like this).

Only on local, not use remote host. There is MIPS architechture of CPU local machine.

I've tried to make it via Scapy, but haven't understood how.

1. Can i send RTS-frame and receive CTS-frame on local machine by Python-scipt?
2. Is it possible to count CPU-cycles between these happenings?
3. If it impossible realize on Python, what i should use?

Thanks in advance.